# What issues besides NaN values in the positions attribute can cause computeBoundingSphere to fail?

Tags: three.js

I'm attempting to use the BufferGeormetry class for the first time. I have a closed path of x,y values that I am attempting to turn into a pyramid with an arbitrary base shape.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.nodelist.length - 1; i++) {
  node = this.nodelist[i];
  next_node = this.nodelist[i + 1];
  positions.push([node[0], 0, node[1]]);
  positions.push([center[0], elevation, center[1]]);
  positions.push([next_node[0], 0, next_node[1]]);
}
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const positionNumComponents = 3;
geometry.setAttribute(
  'position',
  new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), positionNumComponents)
);
```

In my frame of reference, x is left-right, z is front back, and y is up down. So I'm making a sequence of triangles from one base point, to the center, back to the next base point. Then the next continues from the second base point, back to the middle, to the third. The node array has the same point in position 0 and at the end.

The error message is:

```
THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN.
The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.
```

I inspected the positions array and there are no NaN values. what else should I look at? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

I'm using the following source library:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're inserting an array into an array, leading to nested arrays. [Array.push() doesn't require [] as its argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), and neither do `BufferAttribute`s, so you can pass as many values as you need individually outside an []:

```js
// You are nesting an array inside your array
positions.push( [node[0], 0, node[1]] );

// Instead, just add 3 shallow values
positions.push(node[0], 0, node[1]);
```